# Perl Getting a proper Array of Arrays

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm new to perl, and I have trouble using a Cartesian Product. I already found the modules Set::CrossProd and Math::Cartesian::Product, but I can get them to work for my usage because I need to produce an array of.

What I exactly want to do is from a genetic sequence (of variable length, depend on the input), let use for example ARDN, i want all the possible output sequence of this.
I say all because in fact, R means A or G, D means A, G or T and N mean A, T, C, or G.

So what i did, is have an hash of array for the different possible letters, then translate with a loop the input sequence into an Array of array.
So in our example, I should get :

```
@AoA = (
["A"],
["A", "G"],
["A", "G", "T"],
["A", "T", "C", "G"],
);
```

however, it seems that I get an array of scalar, because when I print it, I have the letters that are displayed.

my code :

```
my %alphabet = (                  #not complete for simplification
    A => ["A"],
    D => ["A" , "G", "T"],
    N => ["A", "T", "C", "G"],
);

my @test = (
["A"],
["A" , "G", "T"],
["A", "T", "C", "G"],
);


my $seq = <STDIN>;
chomp $seq;
$seq =~ s// /g;
my @sequence = split(" ", $seq, length($seq));

my @AoA;
for (my $i = 0; $i < $#sequence; $i++) {
  push (@AoA, @{$alphabet{$sequence[$i]}});
};

print "@test";
print "@AoA";
```

Output :

```
ARDN
ARRAY(0x84ea30) ARRAY(0x867780) ARRAY(0x8677f8)
A A G A G T A T C G
```

What did I do wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: When you want to see the detailed contents of any variable: use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($whatever_variable);

Comment: You can simplify your split as `my @sequence = split //,$seq;`

Comment: Your for loop is incorrect. `$#array` gives you the last index, not the size of the array, so you should use `<=`. But better yet, use `for my $s (@sequence)` instead, you'll have each member of `@sequence` in `$s` in the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In perl, an array cannot properly contain another array. Your `push` adds the *elements* of the second list to the array. You should be  pushing references to arrays (and then adapt the rest of your code to expect references).

```
push (@AoA, \@{$alphabet{$sequence[$i]}});
```

Comment: This worked, and now I'm able to do the cartesian product ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Glad to hear it. Since your problem is resolved, please "accept" my answer by clicking on the big checkmark on the left.

Comment: Note that if the contents of %alphabet don't change, and you won't change them via AoA either, you can actually add a the reference directly: `push @AoA,$alphabet{$sequence[$i]}`. The code above will make a copy of the array rather than just point to it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a perfect use case for [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html), which is great when you need to transform a list of things into a new list of things. The bulk of your code could be reduced to the following example, which, in my opinion, is more elegant and clear.

```
my $seq = <STDIN>;
chomp($seq);
my @AoA = map { $alphabet{uc($_)} } split(//, $seq);
```